# C for loop control using difference not giving the result

Tags: c, loops

I was writing this code to keep calculating the sequence 1+(2/2!)+(3/3!)+..... until the difference between two subsequent members of the sequence is 10^-4 however the subtraction is always giving me 0.00 and not stopping the loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int c = 0;
  double sum = 0;
  double fact = 1;
  double seq;
  double temp = 0;

  bool check = false;



    while (check != true)
    {
        c++;
        fact = fact * c;
        seq = c/fact;

        if(temp-seq == 1E-04)
            check = true;

       // printf("%f\n",temp-seq);

        temp = seq;


    }


  printf("stopped at %d operations \n",c);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: temp is not initialized the first time you check it

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Antzi even after initializing it for the first time and setting it as 0 as 0/0! would be equal to 0 , i still got the same problem

Comment: Rage, check out this sniplet: http://codepad.org/IW7cEOvi You can change the `test` to something way smaller and it begins to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, read the other replies, they have good info.
Second, you are not doing the calculations right, se below for a working example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int main()
{
        int     count = 0;
        double  sequence = 0;
        double  previous = sequence;
        double  factorial = 1;

        bool    done = false;



        while (!done)
        {
                ++count;
                factorial = factorial * count;
                sequence += count / factorial;

                if (sequence - previous < 1e-4)
                        done = true;

                printf("%f\n",sequence - previous);

                previous = sequence;
        }


  printf("stopped at %d operations \n", count);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx for taking time to answer the problem , but bigger thx to joachim for pointing out the pointing float theories

Answer (score 2):

The link to "What Every Computer Scientist ..." is there to tell you: don't compare floating-point numbers for exact equality. Ever.

Always use "less than some appropriate distance from the desired answer". In other words, change:

```
if(temp-seq == 1E-04)
```

to

```
if(temp-seq <= 1E-04)
```

Since the chance of hitting the value `1e-4` *exactly* is pretty small.

Comment: I tried that however even then the loop kept going on then i added a printf inside it just to check it , surprisingly the result was always 0.0000 idk why its like that

Answer (score 1):

Checking floating point numbers for equality does not work usually. For two doubles to be equal, all 64 bits have to be equal. Even in case of the slightest inaccuracy, the equality check fails. Try to print `temp - seq` with 20 decimals to see.

Side note: `if (check != true)` is INSANE. It's unreadable and dangerous.
You should simply use `if (!check)`.